# Keep select box dropdown for configurable swatches

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, swatches

Magento 1.9.1, using the `rwd` theme.

Is it possible to set an attribute as a configurable swatch but leave the control in the product page as a dropdown?

I can see that the JavaScript is using swatches to control the dropdown which has been given the class `no-display`

Removing this class and operating the select box in the browser shows this to be the case.

Ideally I really just want the 'different product image per option' part of the configurable swatches, but Magento doesn't seem to offer the ability to do one without the other.

**Can configurable swatches be made to use the original dropdown?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that...

Locate your file style.css and try to add this lines:

```
.product-options .last .input-box .no-display {
  display: block !important;
}
.product-options .last .input-box .configurable-swatch-list {
  display: none !important;
}
```

I hope this helps you.